# How To Structure Architecturally Tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, testing, architecture

I was looking to some smart ways to architecture tests in typescript using `mocha`

To give a better understanding I will explain below my current architecture with it's problems that I have not yet been able to solve conceptually.

### Libraries

- **mocha** as testing framework
- **inversify** used for IoC
- **chai/chai-as-promise** assertion lib

### Mocks

I've implemented a mock abstract class to define all my mocks in the test context

```js
import { injectable } from 'inversify';

@injectable()
export abstract class Mock {
  private static mocks: Mock[] = [];

  constructor() {
    Mock.mocks.push(this);
  }

  abstract clear(): void;

  static async clearAll() {
    for (const mock of Mock.mocks) {
      try {
        await mock.clear();
      } catch (err) {
        // silent
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This class defines only a static method `clearAll` used to clear the state of all my mocks after the full execution, this is done with a specific file `after_all.spec.ts`

```js
import { Mock } from './testlib/mock/mock';

after(async () => {
  await Mock.clearAll();
});
```

Continuing I implement each Mock extending the base abstract class in the following dir

```bash
test
├── after_all.spec.ts
├── repos
│   ├── user_repo.spec.ts
├── testlib
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── mock
│       ├── user_mock.ts
│       ├── index.ts
│       ├── mock.ts (Abstract Mock Class)
└── tsconfig.json
```

```js
import {
  ICreateUser,
  IUser,
  IUserRepo,
} from '../../../src/models';
import { UserRepo } from '../../../src/repos';
import { injectable } from 'inversify';
import { Mock } from './mock';

@injectable()
export class UserMock extends Mock {
  public userCreated: IUser[] = [];

  constructor(@inject(UserRepo) private userRepo: IUserRepo) {
    super();
  }

  unique() {
    const userMock: ICreateUser = {
      name: `test-user-name${Date.now()}`,
      lastName: `test-user-lastname${Date.now()}`,
      email: `test-email-${Date.now()}@test.com`,
      age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    };
    return userMock;
  }

  async saveFromRepo(item: ICreateUser) {
    const user = await this.userRepo.save(item);
    this.userCreated.push(user);

    return user;
  }

  override async clear() {
    for (const user of this.userCreated) {
      try {
        await this.userRepo.delete(user.id);
      } catch (err) {
        // silence the error
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the `index.ts` file I perform the correct binding with inversify for each mock class

```js
import { Container } from 'inversify';
import { UserMock } from './user_mock.ts';


export function setupMockIoc(iocContainer: Container) {
  iocContainer.bind(UserMock).toSelf();
}

export {
  UserMock,
};
```

Then in my `test/testlib/index.ts` file i define a method to initialize all the inversify bindings

```js
Finally i can wrap up all inside each test file 

import 'reflect-metadata';
// tslint:disable-next-line
import 'mocha';
import { Container, injectable, inject } from 'inversify';
import { bindProjectIoC, iocContainer } from '../src/ioc';
import chai = require('chai');
import chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
import { setupMockIoc } from './mock';

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
// chai.use(sinonChai);

export const { expect } = chai;
export { chai };

let iocInitialized = false;

export async function bindIoc(): Promise<Container> {
  if (!iocInitialized) {
    iocInitialized = true;
    bindProjectIoC()
    setupMockIoc(iocContainer);
  }

  return iocContainer;
}
```

```js
import { expect, bindIoc } from './testlib';
import { Container } from 'inversify';
import { UserMock } from './testlib/mock';

describe('User', () => {
  let container: Container;
  let userMock: UserMock
  before(async() => {
    container = bindIoc();
    userMock = container.get(UserMock)
  });

  it('[GREEN] Create User', async () => {
    const uniqueUser = userMock.unique();
    
    const userCreated = await userMock.saveFromRepo(uniqueUser);

    expect(userCreated).is.not.null
  })
});
```

### Considerations

I'm quite comfortable with this architecture, however it has a strong problem in handle relationship between mocks.

When i have two entities, like User and UserProduct, in all the tests related to `UserProduct` i will need for sure also an User, this leads to an increase complexity and possible unstable code

### Suggestions

How do you approach to tests architecture? I don't want specifically help for my implementation, I'm looking for ideas of people that have had experience with this kind of problem, even with other totally different solutions or alternatively suggestions to improve mi current base architecture idea.

Thanks